# How to add background color to Header Banner

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet

I have set all the featured images as the banner of each page in my site.Here is the link - http://constantin-entertainment.info/fixitnow/about-us/ .What I need is to have a background colour like the one I have in my home page which is a slider.Here is the link to home page http://constantin-entertainment.info/fixitnow/ . I have tried putting a div and named a class as featured-img-bg before the image and set the background color which didn't help.Also I have tried adding width which also didn't help.Can please any one help me doing this.Thanks!!
This is the code I have written

```
 <div id="content">
   <div class="container clearfix">


   <div class="featured-img-bg"><a href="http://constantin-entertainment.info/fixitnow/about-us/" title="Permalink to About Us"> <img width="1000" height="390" src="http://constantin-entertainment.info/fixitnow/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/slider.jpg" class="alignleft featured_image wp-post-image" alt="slider"></a></div></div>
```

and the css that I have tried is

```
.featured-img-bg{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E4E4E4 !important;width:1349px;}
```

Comment: would be better if you post the relevant code here. http://jsbin.com/

Comment: I have posted the code

Comment: Please create a bin by going to jsbin.com (As @KheemaPandey has already mentioned) and share the link here so that we can easily help you.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/vimur/1/   Here is the bin I have created, you can check

Comment: I've posted my answer, please check below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to paste the below code just after the div `#header` closed.

```
<div class="featured-img-bg">
<a href="http://constantin-entertainment.info/fixitnow/about-us/" title="Permalink to About Us"> <img width="1000" height="390" src="http://constantin-entertainment.info/fixitnow/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/slider.jpg" class="" alt="slider"></a></div>
```

**CSS would be like this..**

```
.featured-img-bg {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E4E4E4 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    /*width: 1349px;*/ /*Not Required*/ 
}
.featured-img-bg img{float:none} /*Remove the by default added `float:left`*/
```

Check the screenshot for more clearance.
[image]

Comment: I am using wordpres the class align left is automatically generated, so don't know where to edit

Comment: well you can use CSS specifity here..Add this CSS in your css file.

`.featured-img-bg img{float:none;}`